# Cross reference title in LyX

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

I am trying to cross reference the title of a subsection in LyX.

However, when I insert the label and show it in pdf the title is disappering.

Comment: The label should not be in the title itself but in the next line. If this is not helping, please provide a minimal example (copy LaTeX code from View>Source)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do here, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @PhilipPirrip - It worked the way to told me thanks a lot :)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label should not be in the section title. Put it in the next line with standard formatting.